# How to reject requests for php in .htaccess

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, .htaccess

I converted a php site to a rails application (on apache2).
The problem is that old sites requests are still coming in.
So the log has a lot of php request.
That may slow down the site.
I think I can filter them out in .htaccess.
But I'm not familiar with that.

Can you help me with that?

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how big you website is (amount of pages), but isn't it a better idea to do a 301 redirect from the old pages to the new ones. This might be extra work, but saves your users from searching for the new page.

This can also be done by .htaccess

```
Redirect 301 /oldpage.php /newpage.html
```

Or redirect in the php scripts

```
<?php
header( "Status: 301 Moved Permanently" );
header( "Location: http://www.domain.nl/newpage.html" );
exit(0);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

One thing I can imagine of is using mod_rewrite.

```
RewriteRule \.php$ - [F]
```

But I wonder how much performance improvement it would give you. Once, the request reaches Apache HTTPD, it has to process the request and send a response anyway.

Usually, a better approach is to setup a redirect from old URL to new URL. This also ensures that old visitors of your website can reach the right page even with the old URLs have they have. This is considered better than just showing an error to the user.

For example, if you want to redirect all requests of the format: `http://example.com/.../foo.php` to `http://example.com/.../foo/` you can do something like this.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1/ [R=301,L]
```

I haven't tested the regular expressions in the rewrite URLs. They are off the top of my head. But I hope, you get the idea.